# convert a date from a string into a new date field

Tags: sql-server, date, type-conversion

I've got a table I imported from Excel into SQL Server 2012 that refuses to import as a date field.  It comes in as a VarChar that looks like "03/15/2017".  So what I did was create a new Date field in the table, and now I just want to fill that field with the Date version of the text.

I wrote this little Update code to do this:

```
update [dbo].[Sheet5$]
set TDate = CAST(SUBSTRING([Date], 7, 4) + '/' + SUBSTRING([Date], 1, 2) + '/' 
    + SUBSTRING([Date], 4, 2) AS DATETIME)
```

It's giving me an error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it so I can get these dates into a date field?

Comment: `datefromparts()` might be a safer function for you to be more explicit in which parts are going to be the year, month day etc.

Comment: It could be differences in regional settings, or it could be that within that column there are values that are not valid dates. You can identify the problematic rows with [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) -- `SELECT [Date] FROM [dbo].[Sheet5$] WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, [Date], 101) IS NULL` - Here you get no error for a bad input, and with `CONVERT` rather than `CAST` you can specify a style (in this case 101) so that the convert function knows to expect a date in the format `MM/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some invalid data somewhere in your table. You could use TRY_CONVERT or TRY_PARSE instead of CAST if you are on 2012 or later. You also don't need the / characters in there. The ANSI supported format is YYYYMMDD.

```
update [dbo].[Sheet5$]
set TDate = TRY_CONVERT(SUBSTRING([Date], 7, 4) + SUBSTRING([Date], 1, 2) + SUBSTRING([Date], 4, 2) AS DATETIME)
```

Then you can look at the rows where TDate IS NULL and figure out why those rows are invalid and fix the data.

Comment: Thanks for this.  While John's answer worked just as well I gave this the checkmark because it pointed out that bad data existed.  Indeed, someone had input 6/31/2017, and there's no 31st of June.

Comment: There is a 31st June: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/31_June](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/31_June) . Who hasn't heard of the famous Russian tv fantasy musical?! ;)

Comment: Keep in mind, that this will insert NULL-values without warning in case of values that cannot be converted. Better you'd first look for data that cannot be converted to date using a "select * where try_convert... is null".

Comment: @Christian4145 apparently they already have NULL in the table and are trying to update it. Would be easy enough to either check before this or after to fix the source data.

Answer (score 1):

If 2012+ use `try_convert()` in concert with `format()`.  It will not throw an error if you have bogus or malformed data.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Date] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('03/15/2017')
,('3/15/2017')
,('3/7/2017')
,('22/7/2017')

Select *
      ,AsDate   = try_convert(date,[Date]) 
      ,AsString = format(try_convert(date,[Date]),'MM/dd/yyyy')
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Date        AsDate      AsString
03/15/2017  2017-03-15  03/15/2017
3/15/2017   2017-03-15  03/15/2017
3/7/2017    2017-03-07  03/07/2017
22/7/2017   NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyBones Happy to help